# How can i connect private ethereum blockchain using metmask in windows 7?

Tags: ethereum

How can i connect to private blockchain from metamask using windows 7.I have created private blockchain in my pc of windows 10 and i have connected to my network using metamask .I have also connected  another pc with windows 10 to my network from metamask.But when i tried to connected my network another pc which has windows 7 it is not getting connected (I have turned off firewall setting in pc's).Could anyone please help with solution. Thank you in advance.?

Comment: Are all the PCs are in same network? and are you running geth in all the pcs??

Comment: yes, i have solved my problem thank you for reply.